# Concatenate two strings using write() to stdout in C

Tags: c, string, stdout

I'm trying to get two strings written to stdout character by character by two different processes, father and child, being the use of read() and write() compulsory, with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char buf1[100];
char buf2[100];
int i;

pid_t t;

int main()
{
    printf("String1:\n");
    read(0, buf1, 100);
    printf("String2:\n");
    read(0, buf2, 100);
    
    t = fork();
    
    if (t > 0) {
        wait(NULL);
        for (i = 0; i < strlen(buf2); i++) {
            write(1, &buf2[i], 1);
            sleep(1);
            }
        }
    else {
        for (i = 0; i < strlen(buf1); i++) {
            write(1, &buf1[i], 1);
            sleep(1);
            }
        exit(0);
        }
    return(0);
}
```

I manage to get two processes writing each one a single string to stdout, but I'm failing in merging those two strings into one. I've tried to use the ANSI Escape Codes to get the cursor ready for the second string where the first string ends, but how could I integrate them into the buffers inside write()?

Now, with the above mentioned code, I can obtain this output:

```
String1:
Hyper
String2:
loop
Hyper
loop
```

I'd like to obtain:

```
String1:
Hyper
String2:
loop
Hyperloop
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Remove the newlines from the strings you read, then add one as you finish.  Also, you should use the return value from `read()` and `write()` to determine the length of the inputs and outputs.  You're OK with the short strings — but if someone typed more than 100 characters of input, you'd probably get some weird outputs.  Also, writing one character at a time is silly.

Comment: Why are you `fork()`ing?  Why are you `sleep()`ing?

Comment: `read(0, buf1, 100);` reads 100 characters of input - it does not stop at `'\n'`.  It does not form a _string_.  Research `fgets()`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica — If the standard input comes from a terminal, the `read()` calls will usually only read up to the first newline (assuming the terminal is in canonical mode and there is no data queued up waiting to be read; you'd only get 100 characters, of course (no null byte) if the input line is longer than 100 characters).  If the input is not from a terminal, your observation is correct.  This depends on the terminal driver more than anything else.

Comment: Yes @JonathanLeffler, removing the newline from the first string is crucial to come to a solution. I've done it by writing all the bytes of the first buffer except the last one. Thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: Hi @JohnBollinger, I'm forking because I want to have two processes writing each one a string. I'm sleeping because I want to show on the screen how characters are written one by one.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I've found out that the last byte managed by the read() and write() statements corresponds to the newline.

Answer (score 2):

@chux already addressed the main issue. Here is the corresponding working code with the following other changes:

1. localized or eliminated variables
2. added the missing includes to get this to compile on Linux
3. replaced the `write` per character with a sleep with just a single `write` for the entire string
4. guard against buffer overflow
5. define LEN instead of inline magic values, also use STDOUT_FILENO

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define LEN 99
#define str(s) xstr(s)
#define xstr(s) #s

int main() {
    char buf1[LEN+1];
    char buf2[LEN+1];

    printf("String1:\n");
    scanf("%" str(LEN) "s", buf1);
    printf("String2:\n");
    scanf("%" str(LEN) "s", buf2);

    if (fork() > 0) {
        wait(NULL);
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf2, strlen(buf2));
    } else {
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf1, strlen(buf1));
        exit(0);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

and here is the output (note there is no newline after the last line):

```
String1:
Hyper
String2:
loop
Hyperloop
```

Not sure why you print a letter at a time, but the better alternative is just `printf("%s", buf)` (where but is either `buf1` or `buf2`).

Comment: Or, since `write()` appears to be mandated for the output, `write(1, buf1, strlen(buf1))` or `write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf1, strlen(buf1))` (and similarly for `buf2`).

Comment: Also note my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70231158/concatenate-two-strings-using-write-to-stdout-in-c#comment124158872_70231158) to the main question.

Comment: I suggested `printf()` instead of `write()` so it was would easy tag on a `\n` in the format string for after buf2.   `putchar()` or another `write()` is easy too, so not sure how great that argument is. I recently played with unbuffered (`write()`) vs buffered writes (`fwrite()`) and I was surprised how large a difference there was in performance.  Obviously, this is not performance sensitive code.

Comment: One character at a time I/O is feasible but slower.  Even a 16-byte buffer improves the performance dramatically.  Typically, somewhere in the 1-4 KiB range gives you good performance — bigger buffer sizes buy limited extra performance for a lot more space used.  Funnily enough, that tends to be where the standard I/O library (`<stdio.h>`) tends to place its buffer size.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You are obviously right, re read terminating on the newline, but this means I have to fix STDIN_FILENO instead of 0, check return code of read (for -1 and for >1), and overwrite the '\n' (or keep the buffer lengths around which would be sensible anyways), ensure trailing '\0' for good measure perhaps.  `scanf` seemed a more direct route.

Comment: Using `read()` may also behave unexpectedly when hitting the buffer size.  Say, LEN is 2, and user enters `Hyper\n` then first `read` will grab the first letters, 2nd `read` will grab the next two and you get `r\n` sent to the terminal.

Comment: @AllanWind thank you a lot for your answers, but in this case I should use the read() and write() statements. Yes, read() and write() behave quite different in comparison with other C reads and writes.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thank you a lot for the info!!! Really interesting!!! C language is tailored to suit the performance of operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a solution. The last byte read by read() or written by write() correspond to the newline. So writing all the bytes of the first buffer but one is crucial to get the results I want. In this way, the first buffer's for loop would be as follows:

```
for (i = 0; i < strlen(buf1)-1; i++) {
            write(1, &buf1[i], 1);
            sleep(1);
            }
```

And being the complete code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char buf1[100];
char buf2[100];
int i;

pid_t t;

int main()
{
    printf("String1:\n");
    read(0, buf1, 100);
    printf("String2:\n");
    read(0, buf2, 100);
    
    t = fork();
    
    if (t > 0) {
        wait(NULL);
        for (i = 0; i < strlen(buf2); i++) {
            write(1, &buf2[i], 1);
            sleep(1);
            }
        }
    else {
        for (i = 0; i < strlen(buf1)-1; i++) {
            write(1, &buf1[i], 1);
            sleep(1);
            }
        exit(0);
        }
    return(0);
}
```

Thanks a lot to the helpers!

Comment: 1) I am certianl `read(0, buf1, 100);` does not certainly form a _string_ as it can lack a _null character_, so later `strlen(buf1)` is a bust.  2) After fixing that, consider the impact of `i < strlen(buf1)-1` and surprisingly `buf[0] == 0`. Then code is like `i < SIZE_MAX`.  Better as `i + 1 < strlen(buf1)`.  Even better with something like  `len = read(....) ... i < len`.

Comment: Thank you a lot @Reinstate Monica. Regards

Comment: Your terminal, by default, is line buffered, which means if you enter more than 200 bytes, you will end up with the remaining input sent to your shell and it will try to execute that.